# Inputs do not reset after clicking cancel button and reopening the view

Tags: objective-c, forms, uitextfield, cancel-button

I have a form with some text fields, toggles and pickers. Everything works just fine except for When I input something on text fields and click cancel button and reopen the form, inputs are still there. Just can't figure out why.

Now, the app I'm working on is huge. Therefore, can't share everything but here's how my btnCancelClicked method looks like:

```
- (IBAction)btnCancelClicked:(id)sender {
    if(onCompletion) {
        onCompletion(self.myView, YES);

    }
}
```

What's the logic behind implementing a cancel button? What is the step by step process to close the view and not saving whatever the user input is? I'd like to understand what the problem behind this might be. I appreciate any help.

**Edit**: `[self.myView setNeedsDisplay];` or `[self.myView setNeedsLayout];` are not helping.

**Edit2:** TextViews are also working properly, meaning that when I type something and then click cancel and reopen the view is at its initial state. The only problem is with TextFields. Should I do something different for them?

Comment: This is probably on purpose - see if the VC or the text fields have a *restoration id* in storyboard. iOS allows you to do state restoration in a number of ways and I guess this is using one of those. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/restoring_your_app_s_state

Comment: @skaak thanks for the suggestion, but restoration id field looks empty in the inspector. I'll check the link now.

Comment: @skaak I don't think that it has something to do with what was referred in the link you've posted.

Comment: Ok - well that is if you intend to keep the text. Otherwise as mentioned in the answer the view is still retained in memory. The setNeedsDisplay / Layout has nothing to do with it (I recon). Maybe show how the view is presented as well as show the ```onCompletion``` block. I think when you present the view there is some logic that interoperates with the cancel's ```onCompletion``` so that the view is somehow retained in memory - maybe on purpose to return later after a cancel? - and presented again.

Answer (score 1):

After dismissing the view, the view is still in memory. So you get all the entered value as it is. you have two way to achieve your desired outcome:

1. After dismissing the view, set it to nil. create a new view while you are presenting.
2. Before presenting your view, programmatically reset your controls.

you mentioned TextViews are working perfectly, is TextViews created manually?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I set the view to nil in by btnCancelClicked method with `self.view = nil`? Or should I do it in ViewDidDisappear? 

Yes, they are both created manually and assigned to textFields and textViews in DidBeginEditing methods.

Comment: I am not sure, what all things this self.view is used in completion you are calling at the end. you can set inside completion handler, where you are getting self.view.

Comment: I'm using self.view = nil in the completion handler, namely onCompletion block in the btnCancelClicked method, however no change is observed. Probably because I'm only changing the self, but the change is happening somewhere else and setting self to nil is not effecting anything?

Comment: Try to create a new self.view every time when you are adding to view.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi Ali, My point is whenever you are reopening the view. You must be adding to the view hierarchy or presenting it somehow. At that instead of using already create self.view. Create a new instance of view and assign to view and present or add a newly created instance of object.